# Pesquisa com expressão regular

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa com expressões regulares em um json imenso dessa maneira:

```
json = _.filter(dados.responseJSON,function(rst){ 
        return /rst.dst/m == tel
});
```

Mas não está funcionando. O objetivo é fazer a busca como se fosse o `LIKE %valor%` do mysql.

Comment: Podes dar um exemmplo de `rst` e do que queres fazer match? não percebo bem o que queres comparar com o regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não consegue criar uma expressão regular de forma literal passando uma variável pois o js não irá interpretar a variável. O que você pode fazer é criar um objeto `RegExp`:

```
return new RegExp(rst.dst, 'm').test(tel);
```

**Observações:** tenha cuidado com o valor desta variável, visto que alguns caracteres possuem um significado especial e devem ser escapados com `\` (por exemplo `.` e `*`). Outra ponto, tenha certeza de que a variável `tel` existe no escopo da função.